# Android spinner items in popup

Tags: android, android-widget, android-spinner

I have created a spinner which shows its list items like this:
http://developer.android.com/images/ui/spinner.png

however how can i change it so when you tap the spinner it shows all of the options in a new popup?

Comment: you are using api level 11 or higher that's why this spinner shows like your image..

Comment: Are you asking how to show this like context menu insteadOf drop-down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Holo Theme spinner shows as drop-down by default. If you want to customise this
you can use button and set spinner background, when the button taped, show the context menu.

UPDATE :

simply use android:spinnerMode="dialog"

Comment: is there no other work around besides changing the theme or using a button?

Comment: Hi dean.vaughan use android:spinnerMode="dialog"

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,ur-arraylist);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spin.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: this doesn't make a difference

Comment: as Dinesh said im using the Holo theme which seems to be causing the UI change.

Answer (score 0):

To show your spinner items as the popup. use the following lines.

Add the below line above setContentView(R.layout.main).

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

and also add the below line in the particular activity.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

The main.xml will be your own design and the functions may be those items are text view or buttons or radio items.. after clicking each item you need to do the needed work over there..